# Yii. Redirect from Module BeforeControllerAction

Tags: redirect, yii, module

I want to redirect a user to an alternative route if a set of conditions do not match when loading ANY controller inside a Module.

I get the following error:

```
AccessModule and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "redirect".
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you wish to redirect a user before any module controller action is performed???

Answer (score 0):

You probably use `$this->redirect`. You can do like below instead:

```
Yii::app()->request->redirect('URL');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$this->owner->redirect(array("site/index"));
```